# I want to redirect query string URL to specific page. adparch.com/*/*pagenumber=* to adparch.com/projects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got these URLs

`https://www.adparch.com/vi/projects/common-wealth-bank/?pagenumber=2
https://www.adparch.com/projects/Technology--It/oppo?pagenumber=2
https://www.adparch.com/vi-VN/ky-thuat-cong-nghe?pagenumber=4
https://www.adparch.com/vi-VN/du-an?pagenumber=8`

And They got 1 rule contains characters (?pagenumber). I want to redirect all to https://www.adparch.com/project/
I used .htaccess file for redirecting these URLs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagenumber=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /project [R=301,L]
```

But it seems not work. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do some cuts in your rules, please check:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pagenumber=(.*) 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /project/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have used your code, but it's not work for me.Please Look at this picture: http://prntscr.com/oqbl95

Comment: Please, move my modified code in top of your .htaccess file (before # BEGIN Wordpress line).

Comment: Hi JarekBaran. Thank you so much. It's really work. i don't know the position is importance like that. So thank you